# Foundation5 grid column height

Tags: zurb-foundation

Foundation 5 provides grid system and I would like to use it to arrange my web page. But the problem is I dont know how to set the height of each column. now it's just as large as the content needs, but it's really ugly.

I've tried the solution [Set height with zurb-foundation grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717244/set-height-with-zurb-foundation-grid), but it doesnot work. It is a nested grid of 8 columns which is splited into two 6-columns. I just want these two 6-columns to be the same tall but a different background color.

My code is :

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="small-8 columns"> 8 
            <div class="row" > 
                <div class="small-6 columns" id="d8">
                            more and more people want to learn some HTML and CSS.  
                </div>                      
                <div class="small-6 columns" id="d9"> 
                 more and more people want to learn some HTML and CSS. Joining the      
                 designers and programmers are new audiences who need to know 
                 a little bit of code at work (update a content management system 
                 or e-commerce store) and those who want to make their personal 
                 blogs more attractive. Many books teaching HTML and CSS are dry
                 and only written for those who want to become programmers, which 
                 is why this book takes an entirely new approach. </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

and the JS from the link is:

```
<script>
$(window).load(function()({

//equalize function
function equalHeight(group) {
    tallest = 0;
    group.each(function() {
        thisHeight = $(this).height();
        if(thisHeight > tallest) {
            tallest = thisHeight;
        }
    });
    group.height(tallest);
}

//call the equalize height function
equalHeight($("div.small-6"));
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact it is easy to set the height. Finally I use

```
.div[id]
{
    height:85px !important;
}
```

and it works.